# Loop to find and mark with color does not stop - not sure why

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple piece of code - when I run it separately it works and ends normally, however when I run it along with a some other code (they do not refer to each other at any point) the macro is still working in the background - from what I see on the screen the break occurs on this task - not sure why, any tips for a beginner ?

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500")
    Set c = .Find("Urgent", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address            
    Do          
        c.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition of the `Do-Loop` should be like this - `Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress`

Otherwise, the `.FindNext(c)` would start repeating the cells, which were already looped through:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim c as Range
    Dim firstAddress as String

    With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A500")            
        Set c = .Find("Urgent", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
            Do
                c.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```